# GDB help client-server

Tags: debugging, networking, gdb, segmentation-fault

I'm in a computer networking class and I am writing a simple server that just sends and receives messages from the client (which is given). However my server is getting segmentation faults when the given client connects. How can I run GDB to debug this? I try running the server with gdb but it just hangs because there is an infinite while loop in my server and I don't know how to run the client simultaneously to trigger the segfault. Can anyone help?

Comment: i'm assuming your using gnu's compilers as well gcc or g++ did  you try the compiler flag -g ?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to run the client simultaneously to trigger the segfault.

Simple: you open another window, and run the client from *there*.

Answer (score 0):

If your server spawns (fork()) separate process for each connected client, you probably need to set follow fork mode: http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_26.html
"set follow-fork-mode child" will start debugging of the spawned process right after accept() and fork().

Another option is to analyze the core file. Coredumps are mostly disabled by default, so you need to enable them:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Run your server, let it segfault and start gdb pointing it to core and your binary:

```
gdb -c ./core.xxxx ./server
```